# Install4j- Execute uninstaller for older version

Tags: install4j

I have created a **Custom Welcome Screen** from Configurable banner form in install4j application.

[image]

We are showing upgrade and remove option to user if previous installation is found on computer. (Used Radio Buttons for this.)

I want to run **Uninstaller** for previous version, if user select **Remove** option from these 2 options.

I was trying to add action **Uninstall previous installation** in my form but it is not get added in the welcome screen. (Install4j recommend to use it in Installation screen of my installer.)

Is there any other way to achieve this using install4j?

Answer (score 1):

When install4j shows the recommendation to add the "Uninstall previous installation" action to the "Installation" screen, just answer "No" and it will add it to the selected screen.